# Cleveref and Algorithm2e: typesetting procedure name

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, algorithm2e

I am making use of the `procedure` environment of *algorithm2e*, but I am unable to get it to work with *cleveref*. I would like to have a different reference for procedures and algorithms, but they seem to be always treated in the same way. I thought it depended on the counter used, so I tried [this approach by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212030/26355), but the only outcome was on the counter.

If I do not add the `procnumbered` option to *algorithm2e*, `\Cref` outputs "*Algorithm -*".
I could customize the format with `\crefformat` to something like `Procedure \ref{proclabel}`, but in the first place *cleveref* cannot distinguish a procedure from an algorithm, and secondarily I cannot understand what I should override (`\labelcrefformat`? The documentation does not go into much detail).

If I add `procnumbered`, at least I get a number but then the reference name is always "Algorithm".

**What's the best way to get either "*Procedure N*" in the `procnumbered` case, or "*Procedure ProcName*"?**

I looked at [this answer which suggests to create a new float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538933/two-captions-for-algorithm-in-algorithm2e-package) but I'm not convinced it's necessary to go that far, and [this answer which seems to work with hyperref directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336035/setalgorithmname-in-algorithm2e-package-with-a-separate-counter), but I'm a bit wary of touching *hyperref* in this case. There is [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239121/26355) which also recommends a new float but it's for *algorithmicx*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,procnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{procedure}
\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212030/26355
\AtBeginEnvironment{procedure}{\let\c@algocf\c@procedure}
\makeatother
\crefname{proccf}{proc.}{procs.}
\Crefname{proccf}{Procedure}{Procedures}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm.}
    \label{algo:my_algo}
    Call \Cref{proc:my_proc}\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \begin{procedure}
    \caption{MyProc()}
    \label{proc:my_proc}
    \Return{$\emptyset$}\;
  \end{procedure}

  \Cref{algo:my_algo} calls \Cref{proc:my_proc}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Procedure and Algorithm are equal to cleveref]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `\crefalias` besides changing the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,procnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{procedure}
\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212030/26355
\AtBeginEnvironment{procedure}{\let\c@algocf\c@procedure\crefalias{algocf}{procedure}}
\makeatother
\crefname{procedure}{proc.}{procs.}
\Crefname{procedure}{Procedure}{Procedures}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm.}
    \label{algo:my_algo}
    Call \Cref{proc:my_proc}\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \begin{procedure}
    \caption{MyProc()}
    \label{proc:my_proc}
    \Return{$\emptyset$}\;
  \end{procedure}

  \Cref{algo:my_algo} calls \Cref{proc:my_proc}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make it work also without `procnumbered` (and use the procedure label instead of the counter)?